# spring security 3.x + mvc - exception handling

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am new in spring security 3.x so maybe my question is rather silly.

Use case:
Login page, customer enters wrong data (e.g. wrong pasword), then should some error message be displayed on login page

Scenario:
Processing of login end up in my Customer authentication provider with e.g. AuthenticationServiceException. 
Then customer is redirected again to login page

Question:
I have set up controller @RequestMapping(value = "login") for login action.
I would like to know the exception was raised, and I want to display some text (e.g. exception.getLocalizedMessage()) in login action.
How?
How can I catch this AuthenticationServiceException, to let controller know to display something ?

Thank you

Comment: Spring Security already handles this for you and exposes a localized error message already. Why reinvent it again? Also you don't want to tell exactly what is wrong (i.e. *unknow username* or *wrong password*) as that is a hint for hackers to proceed on. You want to have a generic error message (like *unknown username/password combination*).

Comment: How can I access it? How can I realize exception was thrown? Where is this handled by spring security?

Answer (score 0):

When there is an authentication failure, the exception is stored in the model using the name SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION. You can display the exception message on your login page, following example is from a Velocity view:

```
#if ($SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION)
<p class="error">${SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION.message}</p>
#end
```

Comment: I use something like this: Object lastException = webRequest.getAttribute(WebAttributes.AUTHENTICATION_EXCEPTION, WebRequest.SCOPE_SESSION);  What is really silly. The exception remains in session, even you made refresh on login page error is there etc.

Comment: @squirrelInTheBarel feel free to post your approach as its own answer.

Answer (score 0):

I use following in controller:

```
Object lastException = webRequest.getAttribute(WebAttributes.AUTHENTICATION_EXCEPTION,  WebRequest.SCOPE_SESSION);
if (lastException != null) {
    ....
}
```

Then I have acces to last exception.
But this whole concept is little bit silly, e.g. this exception remains in session, so it is displayed every time user make a refresh.
There should be a better solution .....